# Solr Server-Side Query-Preprocessing

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, solr, fuzzy-search

I want solr to do a fuzzy search and also find the query as subword. Matches of complete words shall be prefered.

This works well with the following query:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?qt=my_qt&q=*myword*~0.8+myword~0.8`
�

Is there a possibility to get rid of all the wildcards and fuzzy paramters in the request.

I would love to configure solr an a way so that it does the same search as for the above query when receiving the following query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?qt=my_qt&q=myword
```

I though of adding something like the following to the reqeustHandler in the solrconf.xml

```
<str name="qf">title~0.8+*title*~0.8</str>
```

(this does not work)

Answer (score 0):

See Lucid Imagination's [blog post](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/09/08/auto-suggest-from-popular-queries-using-edgengrams/). You'd probably want to just have one field be the ngram field, and the other field be normal.